# Async pagination and filtering with multiple items on a specific column core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Have a net core 3.1 project where I am trying to filter a large dataset ~200K rows of information. Using the ReflectionIT package for pagination.

I get the "could not be translated" error from the break change to 3.X. I cannot convert it to a list/enumerable first as it takes an extremely long time to process and the PagingList.CreateAsync() requires an IQueryable that implements IAsyncQueryProvider

Also, if I do convert the filtered dataset to a list/enumerable and then back to an AsQueryable() I get the error : "InvalidOperationException: The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IAsyncQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations."

Any ideas on how I can still keep this async and fast while filtering on multiple inputs?

```
            var fixedAssetList = _context.FA_ISA.AsNoTracking();


        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
        {
            var elements = filter.Split(",");
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchOption))
            {
                if (searchOption == "Serialnumber")
                {
                    fixedAssetList = fixedAssetList.Where(s => elements.Any(b=> s.Serialnumber.Contains(b)));
                }
                if (searchOption == "Asset")
                {
                    fixedAssetList = fixedAssetList.Where(s => elements.Any(b => s.Asset.Contains(b)));
                }
                if (searchOption == "AssetDescription2")
                {
                    fixedAssetList = fixedAssetList.Where(s => elements.Any(b => s.AssetDescription2.Contains(b)));
                }
                if (searchOption == "MainAssetno_Text")
                {
                    fixedAssetList = fixedAssetList.Where(s => elements.Any(b => s.MainAssetno_Text.Contains(b)));
                }
            }
        }
        var model =await PagingList.CreateAsync(fixedAssetList, 10, page, sortExpression, "Serialnumber");

        model.RouteValue = new RouteValueDictionary { { "filter", filter }, { "searchOption", searchOption } };
```

Comment: Because of the type conversion error. 'elements' returns an array(string[]), but 's' receives FA_ISA.

Comment: Its a comparison of a string Array and string List though. The code works fine if I have to AsEnumerable() the fixedAssetList first but it takes forever to process since it has to load everything from the table into memory.

Comment: Please try `var fixedAssetList = _context.FA_ISA.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();`. The author of PagingList uses `AsQueryable` in this [blogpost](https://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2017/paging-in-asp-net-core-mvc-and-entityframework-core) when he wants to add a where clause after the query is first defined.

Comment: @JayFridge Get the following error: InvalidOperationException: The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IAsyncQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

Comment: Do you have `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` in your using statements?